# Reassigning value to a variable inside a function in python

Tags: python, loops

I want to run an infinite loop and at every 100th loop i want to print. If I do this : it works perfectly,

```
delay=0

while 1:
delay=delay+1
print(delay)
if delay>100:
    delay=0
    print('100th time')
```

However if I put my if statement in a function it gives error:

```
delay=0
def foo():
    if delay>100:
        delay=0
        print('100th time')
while 1:
    delay=delay+1
    print(delay)
    foo()
```

The error is : UnboundLocalError: local variable 'delay' referenced before assignment.

Is there anyway I can do the reassignment in a function? Putting the entire thing in my while loop would be problematic for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass delay to the function and use modulu(`%`):

```
delay=0
def foo(delay):
    if delay % 100 == 0:
        print('100th time')

while True:
    delay=delay+1
    print(delay)
    foo(delay)
```

Always avoid using `global`s when other effective solutions exist. They increase the complexity of the code significantly.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it avoids the global variable, which is preferable.

Comment: But this `delay` is still a global, it's just that it's being modified by global code, not code inside a function.

Comment: It is modified in its own context, `global` is used to modify global variables in local context, which makes things more complex (usually with no need). The other added value is that `foo` is now a function of its' parameters and does not depend on an external state (easier to reason about, easier to test and debug).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `global`, if you do not want pass `delay` as an argument to `foo`. But it is better to do it that way. Also read: [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

```
delay=0
def foo():
    global delay
    if delay>100:
        delay=0
        print('100th time')
while 1:
    delay=delay+1
    print(delay)
    foo()
```

Comment: While this works, there are probably solutions without resorting to use `global`.

Comment: I agree, this is just one of the ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `global` declaration inside the function as shown below:

```
delay=0
def foo():
    global delay
    if delay>100:
        delay=0
        print('100th time')
while 1:
    delay=delay+1
    print(delay)
    foo()
```

You can also avoid `global` in this case by passing the value in the function `foo()` ans reassign `delay` like `delay = (delay + 1) % 100`.

```
delay=1
def foo(delay):
    if delay == 0:
        print('100th time')
while True:
    delay = delay + 1
    print(delay)
    foo(delay)
    delay = delay % 100
```